# How do you connect a bluetooth wireless mouse to Ubuntu Touch on mobile phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mouse, bluetooth, nexus-4

Most (if not all) bluetooth wireless mice have a usb dongle to connect to PC, Mac, etc.

How can you connect a wireless mouse to a mobile phone (Galaxy Nexus 4, Equarius, Meizu Pro) running Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: Try a USB OTG cable

Comment: I guess that is indeed one way to do it. Any way to make it happen without the need for a USB OTG cable? I was curious to try the whole convergence thing, but I can't if the USB port for the mobile phone is already being used for the external monitor, you know?

Comment: Many wireless mice with dongles are not Bluetooth.  What happens when you put both into pairing mode?  Do they see each other?  Do they pair?  Do they connect?

Comment: @ubfan1, with the conventional bluetooth mice I have, there is no pairing mode, per se. Just a switch: on and off. Maybe I'm using mice with 2.4ghz wireless and not actual bluetooth?

Comment: Bluetooth mice have the bluetooth symbol somewhere on them.  They all have a connect button, and some have an on/off button.  Sounds like your wireless mouse is not bluetooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is get a bluetooth mouse ylthat doea not rely on the sub dongle. I have one, a Microsoft little bluetooth mouse that I have connected to my phone without any Asturias. It works great when connected. This is the one I have https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Bluetooth-Notebook-Mouse-5000/dp/B000TSIAQO

Comment: Thanks @Phil UK, I didn't realize the difference between bluetooth and wireless (2.4ghz). Got me a bluetooth mouse that doesn't require a dongle -- works great now. :)

Comment: @Jesse, glad to hear that you have the correct one now and that it is working for you. I do like using tun mouse with my phone. Makes it easier to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

I also connected a Dell Bluetooth keyboard to my Meizu Pro5. Works like a charm, especially when adding in lots of contacts and web addresses.

Comment: I have not connected a bluetooth. Keyboard yet, but i am looking to get one and see how it performs.